# What are the rules for an Array reference?

Tags: javascript

The following code snippet demonstrates that arrays act like references

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = arr


arr[0] = 5 


console.log(arr2) // [5, 2, 3]
console.log(arr)  // [5, 2, 3]
```

However when I use a map function to edit an array:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = arr

arr = arr.map(x => x * 2) 

console.log(arr2) //[ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(arr)  //[ 2, 4 ,6 ]
```

It doesn't act as a reference. I am expecting it to behave like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = arr

function doubleNumbers(numbers){
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2
  }
  return numbers
}

arr = doubleNumbers(arr)

console.log(arr2) //[ 2, 4 ,6 ]
console.log(arr)  //[ 2, 4 ,6 ]
```

Do the `.map` `.filter` `.reduce` `.forEach` functions create a shallow copy of the array when working with it, returning that?

Comment: [from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) : The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: Read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` method creates and returns a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let arr2 = arr

arr = arr.map(x => x * 2)
```

Here, arr and arr2 are two different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1. Map create the new array so you could assign after the map `arr2= arr`

```js
let arr = [1,2,3]

arr = arr.map(x => x * 2) // return with new array

var arr2 = arr  //declare only after map other wise its target the old

console.log(arr2) //[ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(arr)  //[ 2, 4 ,6 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map does not modify the array in place. Instead, it projects elements into a new array using the supplied method. To understand why it does what it does, one could break it down into an implementation:

```
  Array.prototype.map = function (projection) {
    var mapped = []; // New array
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      mapped.push(projection(this[i]); // Project item into new array
    }

    return mapped; // Return new array
  }
```

Notice how the items of the original array are not modified. The map method follows functional programming paradigms by leaving the elements of the array and the array itself immutable and transforming the original data into a new collection.